# password validation script is not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am using following script to validate password. Aims For validations are :

1. Password field should not be empty
2. Password Length should be between 6 and 10 characters
3. Password should not contain spaces and special characters
4. Password should be Alphanumeric.

But With following code , it passes first 3 aims but even after entering *Alphanumeric* text, it is till alerting:

> "Password Should Contain Alphabet And Numbers Both".

Need your help

Code is :

```
if(document.subForm.password.value==""){
  alert("Please Enter Your Desired Password....");
  document.subForm.password.focus();
  return false;
}
if(document.subForm.password.value.length < 6 || document.subForm.password.value.length > 10){
  alert("Password Length Should Be In Between 6 And 10 Characters.");
  document.subForm.password.focus();
  return false;
}
var re = /^[\w\A-Z]+$/;
if(!re.test(document.subForm.password.value)) {
  alert ("Your Password Has Spaces In Between The Words \n\nOr\n\nIt Contains Special Characters.\n\nThese Are Not Allowed.\n\nPlease Remove Them And Try Again.");
  document.subForm.password.focus();
  return false;
}
var realphanumeric = /^[a-z_A-Z_0-9]+$/;
if (!realphanumeric.test(document.subForm.password.value)){ 
  alert("Password Should Contain Alphabet And Numbers Both");
  document.subForm.password.focus();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If you use notepad++ you can install the regex helper and see whether your regex is doing what is expected.

Comment: Do you have a sample text that is not passing the final regex?

Comment: Limiting password length is a terrible idea, and really limiting password alphabet is also misguided.

Comment: sample text? i didn't get ur point. when i tried 'chplab', it alerts and when used 'chplab22', till it alerts...

Comment: Use http://regex101.com/ for testing your regexes. Also I will just put here link to one js library from dropbox for testing passwords strength https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn

Answer (score 1):

[Aragon0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25163321/338128) suggested to use an open-source [script from dropbox](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) to check password strength. I recommend checking it out.

---

If you'd like one regular expresion to check everything:

```
^\w{6,10}$
```

Explanation:

1. From start (`^` ) to end (`$`) of the string...
2. match only alphanumeric characters (`[A-Za-z_0-9]`),
3. with a length of 6-10 characters (`{6-10}`)

If you want to force the user to have at least one number you can do that like this:

```
^(?![A-Za-z_]+$)\w{6,10}$
```

Comment: It does what the OP wanted to do, but still doesn't work as a good password strength enforcer.

Comment: True... but for some reason s/he doesn't allow special characters and a max lenght of 10, i don't know why. It'll never be really safe this way.

Comment: By helping people solving problems the wrong way, we only help spreading these wrong practices. I think we should offer a better solution and show the OP why his approach is bad.

Comment: @Aragon0 you're 100% right. But with low rep users I'm often inclined to give just answers. I'll edit my answer and refer them to your answer. But my answer is still valid if people ever want to validate an alphanumeric string of 6-10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex

```
/^[a-z_A-Z_0-9]+$/
```

doesn't do what you want. It will match the password "Test" but not "te@st".

You could use two regexes, which both need to match:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
/[0-9]+/
```

Btw, you should not enforce alphanumeric passwords or length constraints. You could use Dropbox's password strength script (https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn)
Some sample code with zxcvbn:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/zxcvbn/1.0/zxcvbn-async.js" />
<script>
var result = zxcvbn(document.subForm.password.value);
if(result.entropy<56) // 56 is very secure, you could also lower it to 48 if you need to.
{
    alert("Your password is too weak. It would be cracked " + result.crack_time_display);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but how will be code after using two regexes ?

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at zxcvbn. Because the password test1234 will pass your password guidelines, but JPWPTaqSvn will not pass (no numbers), 2v8dxaj6dmhUMkPz3bWskSqFfNumw2Ys won't too (too long).